# my img get magnified when I attach in python turtle

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, python-turtle

```
  import turtle

screen = turtle.Screen()
screen.title("Indian State")
image = "Political-Map.gif"
screen.addshape(image)

turtle.shape(image)
```

when i run my code my image get magnified any one know how to fix his problem [image]

Answer (score 0):

The problem here might not be to do with the image being scaled, but instead that the window is too small. You might want to add in a line to change the image size (`screen.setup(width,height)`). I would encourage you however to look into larger projects such as matplotlib. They're a lot more useful, have better documentation, and are much more widely used than turtle.